# React Native project, I follow the guide of Facebook. But it did not work

Tags: xcode, react-native, webstorm

** BUILD FAILED **

The following commands produced analyzer issues:

```
Analyze /Users/evanwang/project/1_reactnative_workspace/rn_demo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
Analyze /Users/evanwang/project/1_reactnative_workspace/rn_demo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
```

(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/evanwang/project/1_reactnative_workspace/rn_demo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn_demo.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn_demo.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

---

If I update package.json, it works.
the default values is the following:
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.46.4",
the following version, it works.
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
        "react-native": "0.44.3",

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue here after upgrading from 0.44.  caches did the trick for me. Here's what I did to get things working again:

1 In the Terminal, navigate to the `react-native/third-party/glog`  folder inside `node_modules` me, this was `cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4)`

2 Once actively in this folder, run `../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh`

3 Glog is configured and the required config.h header file is created for Xcode to find

That work for me , Give a try !!